# European citizen, UK company

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, limited-liability-company, european-union

I am European citizen(Slovenia),and I would like to start selling digital products (mostly to US costumers) via UK LLP or ltd.

LLP seems interesting because, if I understand correctly there would be no UK tax since both me and partner are non-residents and not doing business within UK. However, I am assuming I will have to pay this tax to my home country ?

Another thing is that I am living abroad for years and still changing countries every few months.

I aim at around 50k revenue in the first year and would give myself salary of 12k, everything else would be re-invested.

So, does LLP or Ltd. make more sense for me? Maybe something else?

Comment: Why an UK LLP and not a Slovenian company ? `no UK tax since both me and partner are non-residents` Where did you get this from ? http://incomemadesmart.com/knowledgebase/limited-liability-partnerships/

Answer (score 2):

As a non-UK resident you *might* not have to pay income tax in the UK - but as a company registered in the UK you will still be eligible for corporation tax on you profits. You may also be made to register for VAT depending on your sales figures which can also become liable to EU taxation laws.